# Multiple independent variables / multiple linear regression in Swift

Tags: swift

I am looking for a **Swift** library or code to implement a **Multiple Linear Regression**.  Well, at least that's what I *think* I need.

Right now I've got this, doing just a regular linear regression:

```
private func linearRegression(_ xs: [Double], ys: [Double]) -> (Double) -> Double {


    let sum1 = average(multiply(ys, xs)) - average(xs) * average(ys)
    let sum2 = average(multiply(xs, xs)) - pow(average(xs), 2)
    let slope = sum1 / sum2
    let intercept = average(ys) - slope * average(xs)

    return { x in
        return slope * x + intercept
    }
}

private func multiply(_ a: [Double], _ b: [Double]) -> [Double] {
    return zip(a, b).map(*)
}
private func average(_ input: [Double]) -> Double {
    return input.reduce(0, +) / Double(input.count)
}


let heights: [Double] = [ 20.0, 44.0, 66.0 ]
let ages: [Double] = [ 0.1, 6.5, 12.0 ]

let calc = linearRegression(heights, ys: ages)
print(calc(66.0)) // 12.07
```

So in this case, I've got an input of **heights** (**xs**), and an output/result of **ages** (**ys**).

What I need though, is to have **2** independent variables -- or 2 inputs.  So instead of "**heights -> ages**", I need "**(heights, weights) -> ages**".

So basically, something like this:

```
let heightsAndWeights: [Double] = [ 
    (20.0, 7.2),
    (44.0, 58.0), 
    (66.0, 160.0) 
]
let ages: [Double] = [ 0.1, 6.5, 12.0 ]
```

So in the end, I want to take a **height** and a **weight**, and get back an **age**, in a way that's fit to my input data (**heightsAndWeights**, above).

I've been searching stackoverflow and google and have found a number of implementations in other languages, but they always depend on some library that does the magic.

Swift 5, running on Ubuntu.